# What type is `ios::hex` in?

Tags: c++

I always see `ios::hex` or `ios::basefield`. What type are they in? a class? a variable?

I am trying to find the answer in books, but there are not.

Thanks.

Comment: They are in the ios namespace.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: Maybe you mean "What type are they?"

Comment: [`ios::hex`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/hex/) is a i/o manipulator function - `ios_base& hex ( ios_base& str );`. [`ios::basefield`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa277320%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) is a flag used to indicate the current base format for the stream. `ios::hex` sets the base format to hexadecimal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ios::hex` and `ios::basefield` are bitmask constants actually defined in the class `basic_ios`, which is a base class of `ios`. Their exact type is not specified in the standard, but left to the implementation. It could be an integer type or an enum with some overloaded operators.

Also, `ios::hex` should not be confused with `std::hex` which is a function used as a manipulator for streams. You get them both declared if you include the header `<ios>`.

Answer (score -1):

They are format specifies to the iostream